# Why does translating this code snippet from C# to C++ degrade performance?

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, optimization, suffix-tree

I am much more familiar with C# than C++ so I must ask for advice on this issue. I had to rewrite some code pieces to C++ and then (surprisingly) ran into performance issues.

I've narrowed the problem down to these snippets:

*C#*

```
   public class SuffixTree
    {
        public class Node
        {
            public int Index = -1;
            public Dictionary<char, Node> Children = new Dictionary<char, Node>();
        }

        public Node Root = new Node();
        public String Text;

        public SuffixTree(string s)
        {
            Text = s;
            for (var i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                InsertSuffix(s, i);
        }

        public void InsertSuffix(string s, int from)
        {
            var cur = Root;
            for (int i = from; i < s.Length; ++i)
            {
                var c = s[i];
                if (!cur.Children.ContainsKey(c))
                {
                    var n = new Node() { Index = from };
                    cur.Children.Add(c, n);

                    return;
                }
                cur = cur.Children[c];
            }
        }

        public bool Contains(string s)
        {
            return FindNode(s) != null;
        }

        private Node FindNode(string s)
        {
            var cur = Root;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
            {
                var c = s[i];
                if (!cur.Children.ContainsKey(c))
                {
                    for (var j = i; j < s.Length; ++j)
                        if (Text[cur.Index + j] != s[j])
                            return null;
                    return cur;
                }
                cur = cur.Children[c];
            }
            return cur;
        }
    }
}
```

*C++*

```
struct node
{
    int index;
    std::unordered_map<char, node*> children;

    node() { this->index = -1; }
    node(int idx) { this->index = idx; }
};

struct suffixTree
{
    node* root;
    char* text;

    suffixTree(char* str)
    {
        int len = strlen(str) + 1;
        this->text = new char[len];
        strncpy(this->text, str, len);

        root = new node();
        for (int i = len - 2; i >= 0; --i)
            insertSuffix(str, i);
    }

    void insertSuffix(char* str, int from)
    {
        node* current = root;
        for (int i = from; i < strlen(str); ++i)
        {
            char key = str[i];
            if (current->children.find(key) == current->children.end())
            {
                current->children[key] = new node(from);
                return;
            }
            current = current->children[key];
        }
    }

    bool contains(char* str)
    {
        node* current = this->root;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
        {
            char key = str[i];
            if (current->children.find(key) == current->children.end())
            {
                for (int j = i; j < strlen(str); ++j)
                    if (this->text[current->index + j] != str[j])
                        return false;
                return true;
            }
            current = current->children[key];
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases I'm creating a suffix tree and later using it in a much bigger function which is not relevant for the post (lets call it F()). I've tested both on two randomly generated strings of length 100000. The C# version constructed my suffix tree and used it in F() in a total execution time of: **480 ms** while the code which I've "translated to C++" executed in **48 sec**

I've drilled this down further and it seems that in my C++ code, the constructor takes **47 sec** while using the tree in F() runs at **48 ms** which is 10 times faster than in C#.

**Conclusion**

It seems that the main problem is in **insertSuffix()**, perhaps my lack of knowledge and understanding of the **unordered_map** structure. Can anyone shed a light on this? Did I make some rookie mistake in the C++ variant which causes the object construction to take so long?

**Aditional Info**

I've compiled both the C# and C++ program for maximum speed /O2 (release)

Comment: `for (int i = from; i < strlen(str); ++i)` that's incredibly expensive. On each iteration of the loop, you recalculate the length of the `char*` string. If you are using C++, use `std::string`

Comment: Is it okay if I store the length in a variable before and continue using char*? Are there any other benefits to using std::string? I will test your suggestion in a few.

Comment: Using `char*` is an incredibly bad idea. Use `std::string`. There is *no* reason to use `char*` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: Justin I can confirm that you have provided the solution. I guess I have been looking at it for too long and didn't spot this obvious mistake hehe. Please be so kind to post it as an answer so I can accept and upvote it. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C#, a [System.String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) includes its [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx), so you can get the length in constant time. In C++, a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) also includes its [size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), so it is also available in constant time.

However, you aren’t using C++ `std::string` (which you should be, for a good translation of the algorithm); you’re using a [C-style null-terminated `char` array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte). That `char*` literally means “pointer to `char`”, and just tells you where the first character of the string is. The [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) function looks at each `char` from the one pointed to forward, until it finds a null character `'\0'` (not to be confused with a [null pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr)); this is expensive, and you do it in each iteration of your loop in `insertSuffix`. That probably accounts for at least a reasonable fraction of your slowdown.

When doing C++, if you find yourself working with raw pointers (any type involving a `*`), you should always wonder if there’s a simpler way. Sometimes the answer is “no”, but often it’s “yes” (and that’s getting more common as the language evolves). For example, consider your `struct node` and `node* root`. Both use `node` pointers, but in both cases you should have used `node` directly because there is no need to have that indirection (in the case of `node`, *some* amount of indirection is necessary so you don’t have each node containing another node *ad infinitum*, but that’s provided by the `std::unordered_map`).

---

A couple other tips:

- In C++ you often don’t want to do any work in the body of a constructor, but instead use [initialization lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).
- When you don’t want to copy something you pass as a parameter, you should make the parameter a reference; instead of changing `insertSuffix` to take a `std::string` as the first parameter, make it take `std::string const&`; similarly, `contains` should take a `std::string const&`. Better yet, since `insertSuffix` can see the `text` member, it doesn’t need to take that first parameter at all and can just use `from`.
- C++ supports a [foreach-like construct](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), which you should probably prefer to a standard `for` loop when iterating over a string’s characters.
- If you’re using the newest not-technically-finalized-but-close-enough version of C++, C++17, you should use `std::string_view` instead of `std::string` whenever you just want a look at a string, and don’t need to change it or keep a reference to it around. This would be useful for `contains`, and since you want to make a local copy in the `text` member, even for the constructor; it would not be useful in the `text` member itself, because the object being viewed might be temporary. Lifetime can sometimes be tricky in C++, though, and until you get the hang of it you might just want to use `std::string` to be on the safe side.
- Since `node` isn’t useful outside of the concept of `suffixTree`, it should probably be inside it, like in the C# version. As a deviation from the C# version, you might want to make the type `node` and the data members `root` and `text` into `private` instead of `public` members.

Comment: Wow I've learnt a lot today, thanks for the detailed elaboration! I was closer to C style syntax than C++.. even my Intellisense was confused underlining errors that weren't there.

Comment: @Ilhan To efficiently translate that to C instead of C++, you would need to keep track of the length separately so you don’t need to call `strlen` all the time. I also just added a tip at the end about putting `node` inside `suffixTree`; C++ supports this just like C# does, and it provides the same encapsulation benefits.